# How can I save the inputted work if the user types "Stop"

Tags: c#

What is the easiest way you can save this information if the user were to type "Stop." So if i reopened the program the information would still be their.
Ask me if you need help clarifying what I mean.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace LibraryWork
{

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var bookList = new List<string>();
            string ansSearch = String.Empty;
            string search = String.Empty;
            int i = 1;
            for (int zero = 0; i > zero; i++)
            {
                Console.Write("Type ");
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan;
                Console.Write("'New'");
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
                Console.Write(" if you would you like to enter a new book. Type ");
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                Console.Write("'List' ");
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
                Console.Write("to see a list of books entered. Type ");
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
                Console.Write("'Search' ");
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
                Console.Write("to look up a specific book.");
                Console.Write(" And if you want to exit. Type ");
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                Console.Write("'Stop'.");
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
                Console.WriteLine();




                string answer = Console.ReadLine();

                if (answer == "Stop")
                {
                    return;
                }

                if (answer == "New")
                {
                    Console.Write("Please format the Entry of your book as follows: ");
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                    Console.Write("'Name of the Book',");
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
                    Console.Write("'Author (first, last)',");
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkGreen;
                    Console.Write("'Category',");
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkYellow;
                    Console.Write("'Dewey Decimal Number'.");
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    bookList.Add("Entry " + i + ": " + Console.ReadLine());
                    continue;
                }
                if (answer == "List")
                {
                    bookList.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
                    Console.WriteLine("Press enter to continue");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    i--;
                    continue;
                }
                if (answer == "Search")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("What would you like to search for (Title: Full Title; Author: first, last): ");
                    search = Console.ReadLine();
                    var results = bookList.Where(x => x.Contains(search)).ToList();
                    bool isEmpty = !results.Any();
                    if (isEmpty)
                    {
                        i--;
                        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                        Console.WriteLine("Sorry, we could not find that.");
                        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
                        continue;
                    }
                    foreach (var result in results)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(result);

                    }




                    Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to continue");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    results.Clear();
                    i--;
                    continue;
                }
                i--;
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                Console.WriteLine("Incorrect Response, please try again");
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
            }

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You have to save this information in database on in a file.

Comment: And I also figured out that you post these questions for fake reputation for other account @thePreplexedOne :D

Comment: I am not posting fake questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `bookList` is a `List<string>`, you could use:

```
File.WriteAllLines("books.txt", bookList);
```

I'd recommend escaping your for loop using `break;` when they type "Stop" and then implement the code I provided above after the for loop.

And load it back up when the application starts, assuming the file exists:

```
if(File.Exists("books.txt"))
{
    bookList = File.ReadAllLines("books.txt").ToList();
}
```

Based on what I said, here is the full code for what I'm talking about:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;

namespace LibraryWork
{

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var bookList = new List<string>();
            if(File.Exists("books.txt")) //Check if file exists.
            {
                bookList = File.ReadAllLines("books.txt").ToList(); //Load the file and convert it to a list.
            }
            string ansSearch = String.Empty;
            string search = String.Empty;
            int i = 1;
            for (int zero = 0; i > zero; i++)
            {
                Console.Write("Type ");
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan;
                Console.Write("'New'");
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
                Console.Write(" if you would you like to enter a new book. Type ");
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                Console.Write("'List' ");
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
                Console.Write("to see a list of books entered. Type ");
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
                Console.Write("'Search' ");
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
                Console.Write("to look up a specific book.");
                Console.Write(" And if you want to exit. Type ");
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                Console.Write("'Stop'.");
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
                Console.WriteLine();




                string answer = Console.ReadLine();

                if (answer == "Stop")
                {
                    break; //Escape the loop.
                }

                if (answer == "New")
                {
                    Console.Write("Please format the Entry of your book as follows: ");
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                    Console.Write("'Name of the Book',");
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
                    Console.Write("'Author (first, last)',");
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkGreen;
                    Console.Write("'Category',");
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkYellow;
                    Console.Write("'Dewey Decimal Number'.");
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    bookList.Add("Entry " + i + ": " + Console.ReadLine());
                    continue;
                }
                if (answer == "List")
                {
                    bookList.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
                    Console.WriteLine("Press enter to continue");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    i--;
                    continue;
                }
                if (answer == "Search")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("What would you like to search for (Title: Full Title; Author: first, last): ");
                    search = Console.ReadLine();
                    var results = bookList.Where(x => x.Contains(search)).ToList();
                    bool isEmpty = !results.Any();
                    if (isEmpty)
                    {
                        i--;
                        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                        Console.WriteLine("Sorry, we could not find that.");
                        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
                        continue;
                    }
                    foreach (var result in results)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(result);

                    }




                    Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to continue");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    results.Clear();
                    i--;
                    continue;
                }
                i--;
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                Console.WriteLine("Incorrect Response, please try again");
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
            }
            //We end up here after breaking from the loop.
            File.WriteAllLines("books.txt", bookList); //Save our list of books.
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank You so Much!